# Will the circuit work if I replace the two transistors with other NPN transistors?

Tags: transistors, switch-mode-power-supply

Will the circuit work if I replace the two transistors with other NPN transistors?

[image: Schematic Switch Mode Power Supply]

<sub>Source: [Google Drive page](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TWNf6OfTSGOfDitfw5u4qp9Hvs_lkU74/view) linked in the description of YouTube video "[How does a mobile charger work? SMPS with Opto-Coupler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2N_T7VFymFg)" by "[Explorer](https://www.youtube.com/@ExplorerStuff)"</sub>

Comment: What ‘other’ transistors were you considering? The T13001 is somewhat specialised as it is a high voltage switching transistor. The S8050 is fairly generic. Also note that some of the other components are rather critical for safety and there’s defects in the schematic. You might want to reconsider using this.

Comment: i would like to replace transistor S8050 with transistor C9013. Btw thanks for the advice

Comment: To be precise, the rms value of the public electricity grid voltage in Europe is 230V and not 220V.

Answer (score 3):

Because this circuit uses mains voltage, I would recommend against any tinkering. If you have to ask strangers on the internet about suitable replacement transistors, this circuit is possibly quite dangerous for you.

If you do intend to make this circuit, against advice, I would recommend that you use a ground-fault current interrupter (GFCI) a/k/a Residual Current Device (RCD) outlet, to reduce the chances of electrocution. I would also add a fast-blow fuse to reduce the risk of fire.

The note about the resistor between the mains supply and the diode bridge concerns me greatly. It puts into question the skill level of the person who made the schematic, and puts into question the level of current that the circuit is suppose to draw. The transistors are small in a TO-92 package. One wonders, whether the original value of 260 k\$\Omega\$ is correct, and 2.6 \$\Omega\$ is a mistake that will cause the circuit to release magic smoke, if not start a fire. In fact, one wonders whether it might not be a resistor at all, but a capacitor. The maker of the schematic obviously didn't *test* the component before releasing the original schematic, or they would have known whether it was a 2.6 \$\Omega\$ or a 260 k\$\Omega\$ resistor (or if it was a capacitor).

---

Edit: It occurred to me that some (younger) readers might not be aware that capacitors might be confused with resistors. So, I am adding an example below. The items on the left are capacitors. Those on the right, resistors.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xc13.jpg]

<sub>Source: Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange question: "[Odd 220 pF capacitor form factor, how to read markings, what type and what for?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/602808)" by [Stephan Neuhaus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/285783/stephan-neuhaus)</sub>

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: I have never come across capacitors like those on the left, and I started working in electronics in the 70s

Answer (score 3):

The transistors are extremely common jellybean parts. The S8050 is a 'jellybean' NPN small signal TO-92 transistor and the 13001 is a high voltage (typically 600V) transistor with some resemblance to the original Motorola MJE13001.

Both come in numerous variations from a plethora of suppliers.

The 13001 can be sourced in a TO-92 (or SOT-89 by times) easily, though the original was in a mid-power package TO-225, if memory serves.

The S8050 is available in multiple pinouts of TO-92, in the common SOT-23 , and some makers offer it with large die or small die or similar variations.

Pretty much any small signal NPN transistor should work in the S8050 slot. The high voltage transistor is a lot more critical.

The circuit is a cheap self-oscillating converter that avoids the few pennies for a dedicated chip and the fraction of a penny for a proper voltage reference. It has the usual hazards of anything mains-connected and additional hazards from possible construction issues (including the transformer construction). The '102nF' capacitor is likely supposed to be 1nF and **must** be Y-rated for safety. There is no overvoltage protection. It would be most unwise to connect anything you value to the  output.

Comment: Thank you so much